# How to set CalendarView date with Text

Tags: android, calendar

I want to concatenate my selected date with String(called from database). I have my custom db which holds birthday records. I want to write Text / slogan beside date . 
For example  today is 3-9-2015.for date 3 application should write (Happy birth day text beside date).
I have explored alot . i found calendar.draw(); in which i put a canvas by writing a text over it... but failed to display.

Currently i am using

```
TextView bday = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            bday.setText("Happy BDay");
            calendar.addView(bday);
```

This code working fine and placing text but not on selected date...Kindly help.

regards

Comment: Didn't get you what you want to do? Do you want to show text in header of CalendarView????

Comment: no i want to put string text on selected date

Comment: i need similar functionality in calender view ...can you please guide what should to do http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/08/aCalendar.jpg